# How to get contents of an AWS S3 bucket programmatically in Python

Tags: python, command-line, minio

I can run command `aws --profile minio s3 ls s3://aa/bb/` in a terminal successfully to get the contents of that particular bucket on minio, but when I run below code in Python, it returns an empty string.

```
import os
stream = os.popen('aws --profile minio s3 ls s3://aa/bb/')
stream.read()
```

And when I change the second line so that I query the contents of a **local** folder instead, like `stream = os.popen('ls /Users/cc/')`, the contents of that local folder are printed successfully as well.

When I execute the first command using `os.system('aws --profile minio s3 ls s3://aa/bb/')`, it returns `256` as the output.

So how to access the contents of a minio bucket programmatically in Python?

Comment: Is [this](https://docs.min.io/docs/python-client-quickstart-guide) related/relevant?

Comment: Yes, perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With the caveat that I haven't used minio, here's how I'd use `boto3` (the AWS python sdk) in a python script to do what your CLI command does:

```py
import boto3

session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name='minio')
client = session.client('s3')

response = client.list_objects_v2(
    Bucket='aa',
    Prefix='bb',
)

for item in response['Contents']:
    print(item['Key'])
```

[boto3 on GitHub](https://github.com/boto/boto3)

[boto3 docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html)